# SUM of zero's creating problems

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I want to store zero in one of column in Hbase. So, i did the following in the Pig script.

```
    data = load 'access_log_Jul95' using PigStorage(' ') as (ip:chararray, dash1:chararray, dash2:chararray, date:chararray, date1:chararray, getRequset:chararray, location:chararray, http:chararray, code:int, size:int);

splitDate = foreach data generate  0 AS size:int , ip as ip,  FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(date, ':')) as h;

groupedIp = group splitDate by h.$1;
```

and then i am doing like this

```
a = foreach groupedIp generate SUM(splitDate.size);
```

which is throwing error on console like

```
 Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast
```

Is there any way that i can always write zero in this case with out using SUM or way that SUM works with all zeros here would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Give your sample data aswell...it will be hepful if the data is available

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
data = load 'access_log_Jul95' using PigStorage(' ') as (ip:chararray, dash1:chararray, dash2:chararray, date:chararray, date1:chararray, getRequset:chararray, location:chararray, http:chararray, code:int, size:int);

splitDate = foreach data generate  0 AS size:int , ip as ip,  FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(date, ':')) as (h1:chararray,h2:chararray,h3:chararray);

groupedIp = group splitDate by h1;

a = foreach groupedIp generate SUM(splitDate.size);
```